# What is the fastest way to find all the file with the same inode?

Tags: linux, bash, inode

The only way I know is:

```
find /home -xdev -samefile file1
```

But it's really slow. I would like to find a tool like `locate`.
The real problems comes when you have a lot of file, I suppose the operation is O(n).

Comment: Cf. http://superuser.com/questions/97367/is-it-possible-to-find-all-files-with-a-given-inode-efficiently/97417#97417

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way:

- Use `find -printf "%i:\t%p` or similar to create a listing of all files prefixed by inode, and output to a temporary file
- Extract the first field - the inode with ':' appended - and sort to bring duplicates together and then restrict to duplicates, using `cut -f 1 | sort | uniq -d`, and output that to a second temporary file
- Use `fgrep -f` to load the second file as a list of strings to search and search the first temporary file.

(When I wrote this, I interpreted the question as finding all files which had duplicate inodes. Of course, one could use the output of the first half of this as a kind of index, from inode to path, much like how locate works.)

On my own machine, I use these kinds of files a lot, and keep them sorted. I also have a text indexer application which can then apply binary search to quickly find all lines that have a common prefix. Such a tool ends up being quite useful for jobs like this.

Answer (score 10):

There is no mapping from `inode` to name. The only way is to walk the entire filesystem, which as you pointed out is O(number of files). (Actually, I think it's θ(number of files)).

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but many versions of `find` have an `inum` option to match a known inode number easily. You can do this with the following command:

```
find . -inum 1234
```

This will still run through all files if allowed to do-so, but once you get a match you can always stop it manually; I'm not sure if `find` has an option to stop after a single match (perhaps with an `-exec` statement?)

This is much easier than dumping output to a file, sorting etc. and other methods, so should be used when available.

Comment: Great answer. Even my old gentoo server has find `-inum` option.

Comment: To stop on first match you can try something like `find . -inum 1234 | head -n1`.

Comment: That does the same thing as `-samefile` only you have to find the inode yourself. It makes things even slower.