# Find the path of the file by inode

Tags: php, linux, inode

Is there a way to get the full path to the file based on its `inode` number ?

```
$inode = fileinode($path);
$path = ???
```

Comment: hey there is a similar question on SO, maybe that will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340263/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-all-the-file-with-the-same-inode

Comment: Most filesystems store names in parent folder. So I guess you got to bruteforce search starting from root. Can take days maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `ffind` tool on [Sleuth Kit Libary (TSK)](http://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/), might help you.

`ffind` finds the names of files or directories that are allocated to inode on disk image image. By default it only will only return the first name it finds. With some file systems, this will find deleted file names.

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP snippet works for me:

```
$Command = "find ".__DIR__." -inum ".$Inode." -print";
$Result = shell_exec($Command);
```

Sources:

- William E. Shotts, Jr. "The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction", pg. 36
- http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=211473

Comment: shell_exec is oftbanned